# ASP.NET MVC5 custom json model binder with html content

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-model-binder

I used the FromJsonAttribute (created by [Steve Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/)), it's quite great, but sadly it doesn't pay attention to the AllowHtml attribute. I have the following model:

```cs
public class HKNewsPaperViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string RPublisher { get; set; }

    public string REditor { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool IsDraft { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    public List<HKNewsItemViewModel> NewsItems { get; set; }

    public HKNewsPaperViewModel()
    {
        NewsItems = new List<HKNewsItemViewModel>();
    }

}
public class HKNewsItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Link { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I receive data this way:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New([FromJson] HKNewsPaperViewModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

FromJson attribute looks like this:

```cs
public class FromJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    private readonly static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new JsonModelBinder();
    }

    private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var stringified = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[bindingContext.ModelName];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringified))
                return null;
            return serializer.Deserialize(stringified, bindingContext.ModelType);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't pass html content where the AllowHtml attribute is there. Thanks a lot!